# org.apache.flink.examples.java.clustering.util.KMeansDataGenerator: no found

Tags: apache-flink

when running KMeans.jar in the examples dirctory,there are some mistakes,and the version that is flink-0.10.1-bin-hadoop1-scala_2.10
my running env is cygwin64 and mistakes as follow:

`root@HIH-D /cygdrive/d/Development/flink-0.10.1-bin-hadoop1-scala_2.10/flink-0.10.1/kmeans`

Running

```
# java -cp ../examples/KMeans.jar:../lib/flink-dist-0.10.1.jar org.apache.flink.examples.java.clustering.util.KMeansDataGenerator -points 500 -k 10 -stddev 0.08 -output `pwd`
```

gives a

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.examples.java.clustering.util.KMeansDataGenerator
```

Comment: Just a note to other SO users. "错误: 找不到或无法加载主类" is a "class not found exception" (according to google translate)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this out locally and it worked.
I think the classpath (`-cp`) argument is not set correctly.

Can you try to do `jar tf ../examples/KMeans.jar` from the directory you are calling the KMeansDataGenerator? (in: `D /cygdrive/d/Development/flink-0.10.1-bin-hadoop1-scala_2.10/flink-0.10.1/kmeans`).

```
robert@robert-da ~/incubator-flink/build-target (git)-[flink3003] % mkdir kmeans
robert@robert-da ~/incubator-flink/build-target (git)-[flink3003] % cd kmeans
robert@robert-da ~/incubator-flink/build-target/kmeans (git)-[flink3003] % java -cp ../examples/KMeans.jar:../lib/flink-dist-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.flink.examples.java.clustering.util.KMeansDataGenerator
KMeansDataGenerator -points <num> -k <num clusters> [-output <output-path>] [-stddev <relative stddev>] [-range <centroid range>] [-seed <seed>]
```